# If statement in Django not displaying the output

Tags: django, if-statement

I want to display a delete button alongside comments that the request.user has written so that only they can remove them, but for some reason can't get my if statement to work. Here is my template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    ...
    {% if post.comment_set.all %}
        {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
            <img src="{{ comment.user.image }}">
            <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
       
            {% if comment.user == request.user %}
                # delete icon with modal
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is the `if comment.user == request.user` tag which is not working. I have tried outputting both `comment.user` and `request.user` in `<p>` tags and both display the way I would expect, so can't understand why it doesn't work. I have also tested the delete button which does display correctly when the if statement is removed.

Here are my relevant models for reference:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image= models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default='profile_pics/default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Strangely, further up the page I have used similar code to display delete beside the blog posts themselves, using `{% if post.author.user == request.user %}`. Based on this I have tried changing my redundant if tag to `comment.author.user`, `comment.post.author`, `comment.post.author.user` and other variations and so far nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is the request object being included in the context?
You might need to add the request to the context processors block in settings.py
include this

```
'django.template.context_processors.request',
```

like so, and the request.user will be available in template variables.

```
TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates'],
            'OPTIONS': {
                'debug': DEBUG,
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.media',
                    'django.template.context_processors.static',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes my settings.py does already include this line of code. It seems the problem does not lie with `request.user` since I have previously been able to output that without issue

Comment: ahh- ok.
have you tried `{% if comment.user.user == request.user %} ` ?

Comment: That must have been one of the only combinations I hadn't tried, and that did the trick! Brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: The `user` in `user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` on the models might be better written as `profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` .  

Allowing {% if comment.profile.user == request.user %}

Comment: Ahh I see. Now it makes sense. Awesome thanks again, that has really helped!